# DbGeography make circle with center and radius

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, geo

I create a DbGeography-point like this:

```
String selectedLocation = String.Format("POINT ({0} {1})", lon, lat).Replace(",", ".");
DbGeography selectedLocationGeo = DbGeography.FromText(selectedLocation, 4326);
```

I also have a radius R.

I want to create a curvepolygon with the shape of a circle with the specified radius from the point-coordinate. Be aware that I am using DbGeography, and not DbGeometry.

How do I create the CIRCULARSTRING? Or is there a better way than using a CIRCULARSTRING?

---

Something like this perhaps?

```
String polyString = String.Format("CURVEPOLYGON(CIRCULARSTRING(xx yy, xx yy, xx yy, xx yy, xx yy))");
DbGeography polygon = DbGeography.FromText(polyString, 4326);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Create a [DbGeography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography(v=vs.110).aspx) Circle by creating a [PointFromText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.pointfromtext(v=vs.110).aspx) and then Buffer that point by the radius.  For the WGS84 coordinate system the DbGeography radius units appear to be in kilometers.

```
string textPoint = String.Format("POINT ({0} {1})", longitude, latitude);
DbGeography point = DbGeography.PointFromText(textPoint, DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId); //4326 = [WGS84]
DbGeography targetCircle = point.Buffer(radiusKilometers);
```

Edited with info from [adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016302/adrian) about DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can use `DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId` instead of the magic number 4326, since WGS84 is the default system used. Also, I found that the unit for the argument to `Buffer` is metres, not kilometres.

Comment: Good point on the DefaultCoordinateSystemId.  I did have quite the time with the Buffer units.  Everything I could find online pointed to meters, but unit tests using circles from Google Maps (radius meters) only appear to work out with kilometers used for the Buffer units.  Originally questioned this due to circle around Arizona would create exception - radius/geom larger than earth - or some such.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @EricConway and the comment adrian
I research about the radius getting the wtk using AsText function and displaying on a map and the radius is in meters.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Buffer method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506085(v=vs.110).aspx

It creates a circular buffer around a point.
It can be used on other types of geometries/geographies as well.

Be careful if the radius is quite big when using for geography (few kilometers should be OK)

I am not sure how it is implemented in C# but I would definetely use that in other spatial tools.